# JPA : Entity is changed but find query returns the same entity

Tags: jpa-2.0

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(em.find(Suggestion.class,Integer.parseInt(suggId)));
em.getTransaction().commit();

cas_e = em.find(Case.class, cas_e.getId());
```

Here suggestions are mapped to case entity, and although one of the suggestions from suggestions list is deleted the last row returns the same count of suggestion:

```
@Entity
Case  {
private List<Suggestion> suggestions;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "caze", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<Suggestion> getSuggestions() {
        return (suggestions);
    }

    public void setSuggestions(List<Suggestion> suggestions) {
        this.suggestions = suggestions;
    }
}

Suggestion {
private Case caze;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="case_id")
    public Case getCaze() {
        return caze;
    }
    public void setCaze(Case caze) {
        this.caze = caze;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
...
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
...
```

Comment: ok em.detach(cas_e); before find solved the problem, but I don't know why exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are in a transaction and querying for an entity that is already loaded and managed.

When you query for managed items, the persistence provider will first look into the current persistence context. So in your case this means that you will get the same instance of the entity back.

If you want the managed instance to reflect the changes from the DB, you can either detach and then query (tedious), or refresh:

```
em.refresh(cas_e);
```

EDIT: if it is not certain, whether the instance is manages at refresh time, you can merge it first. Merge doesn't care if you pass an already managed entity to it:

```
cas_e = e.merge(cas_e);
em.refresh(cas_e);
```

Comment: i tried with em.refresh(cas_e); and it says that cannot refresh unmanaged Entity. It's strange because I'm using this in ViewScoped bean and this entity should be managed all the time. Whatever... detach is working though. Thank you for the answer

Comment: This is in fact strange. Refresh does expect a managed entity. But if hte behavior changes on detach, I would assume a managed entity. Do you by any chance detach first and then refresh? If not, you can make sure the entity is managed by merging it, see the edit.

Comment: Could you, instead of detaching clear the cache: `em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();` and see whether it changes the behaviour?

Comment: em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();  it's not working. Seems it's not cache problem. =============
cas_e = em.merge(cas_e);
     em.refresh(cas_e);(without find) did the job